# How do I get log4J to work - I'm getting "package org.apache.log4j does not exist"

Tags: configuration, log4j

i know this may be a newbie qestion, but I'm having issues with setting up Log4J:

I want to run a log4j demo,  and here's my code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class HelloLOG4j {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Hello.class);

  public static  void main(String argv[]) {
 BasicConfigurator.configure();
 logger.debug("Hello world.");
 logger.info("What a beatiful day.");
  }
}
```

I set my Classpath:
C:\Users\Adel\Downloads\apache-log4j-1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar
in both System and User var's

[image]

But when I run my program I still get

```
errors found:
File: C:\Users\Adel\Desktop\various_topics\JavaProjects\HelloLOG4j.java  [line: 2]
Error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
```

I know that I set classpath right - if I run cmd line:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20>print %LOG4J_HOME%
C:\Users\Adel\Downloads\apache-log4j-1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar is currently bein
g printed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add log4j home to the classpath as the JVM needs the path to the log4j classes

if on windows, you can use

```
set classpath=%classpath%;%LOG4J_HOME%
```

On linux/ ubuntu (much better than windows for development & servers)

```
export classpath=$classpath:$LOG4J_HOME
```

then run your app after adding other paths to classpath
like

```
set classpath=%classpath%;c:\users\adel\....
```

You do not need to add log4JHOME again - as `%classpath%;` will add to the current classpath.

LOG4J_HOME is not known to Java. It is just used by log4j in case of auto config/default config.

On a side note try using the new log4j2 !

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how you are trying to compile the code?

And also, try adding the log4j.jar to 'lib' directory and compile with the classpath referencing this jar

Comment: I compiled using both Eclipse and DrJava, by the usual method. Hmm, log4j.jar to 'lib' directory OK, lemme see

Comment: Yes, try adding the jar to lib directory and make sure that the jar is in added to the classpath

Comment: oK I just added it to java's lib directory. will see

Comment: No, it didn;t . let me try smth else , perhaps trying to extract the jar file?  i.e when i DL'ed log4j it's one package and lots of files, including log4j.jar

Comment: You must have downloaded a different zip file. Download log4j binaries and extract the zip and pick only the log4j.jar and add it to classpath

Comment: Try "jar -tf log4j-1.2.17.jar" to check whether package org.apache.log4j exists.

Comment: @JintianDENG - hey, yep I just did that and it exists . it showed me a big listing too

Comment: lib is just a utility folder used by IDE to scan. can be anywhere as long as its in classpath at run time

Comment: dont add things to java lib.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to remind that don't capitalized `Log4j` keyword , unlike `Logger`:

```
import org.apache.Log4j.Logger; //typo
import org.apache.log4j.Logger; //correct
```

`/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2-api-2.8.2.jar` path can be located by issue `dpkg -L liblog4j2-java`(debian-based) command, then do:

```
$ sudo javac -cp .:xxx.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2-api-2.8.2.jar xxx.java
```